# Do CA Public Audit Records increase the visibility, and risk of attack?

Tags: tls, certificates

Does the CA feature of Public Audit Records increase the visibility of my hosts, and therefore the risk of host-specific attacks?

Would the only mitigation be to only enable this for wildcard certificates?

Answer (score 1):

Wildcarding your certs as a countermeasure would be considered *security by obscurity* and as such is not really helpful.

Your sites can be listed in other databases and there is only finite number of IP addresses out there anyway so it doesn't really matter how hard you try to hide.

Eventually they'll find you and you have to be prepared for them. It can be either a random attack which usually isn't that bad for you to protect from it by obscuring the way to you or it can be a directed attack from someone who knows the way already.

I'd say there are much more important consideration when it comes to securing your host.